# ¿Cómo puedo bloquear una web por horas usando php?

Tags: php

```
<?php
  $hInicio = 15;   // Está en 24 hrs
  $hFin = 18;

   $h = date("G");  // Hora actual en 24 hrs

   if ($h >= $hInicio && $h <= $hFin) header("location: bloqueo.html");
?>
```

He intentado con el siguiente código pero no me funciona, no sé como usarlo.
Quiero implementarlo para poder bloquear una parte de mi página.
Gracias por su ayuda (y) .

Comment: y la variable $h te genera las 24 horas?

Comment: A que te refieres con que no te funciona. Has probado cambiar la hora del servidor o el rango de tu condición???

Comment: No @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas , apenas vi ese codigo en internet  y solo edite los primeros valores, suponiendo que eran precisamente las horas de ingreso y las modifique por unas horas fuera mi hora actual pero no me redirige a un archivo llamado bloqueo.html.

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez no he hecho el print, en un momento lo hago y te respondo

Comment: olle y como se va a cumplir la condición ? actualizando la página?

Comment: revisa lo que te devuelve date('G') porque no entra en la condición, yo he hecho algunas pruebas y el header no es tu problema.

Comment: voy a colocarle algo que me falto, lo del set default time zone a la hora de mi pais a ver que me trae

Comment: AJA! me trae 14 ahora

Comment: entonces ya ves que todo era con ver la condición ;P

Comment: see . gracias @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es porque `date("G")` te devuelve un string, conviertelo a entero:

```
<?php
  $hInicio = 15;   // Está en 24 hrs
  $hFin = 18;
  $h = (int)date("G");  // Hora actual en 24 hrs

  if ($h >= $hInicio && $h <= $hFin) header("location: bloqueo.html");
?>
```

**NOTA:** `date("G")` devuelve el formato de 24 horas de una hora sin ceros iniciales con valores de 0 hasta 23.

---

Edición: En base a lo que me has dicho, al hacer `var_dump((int)date("G"));` te muestra el valor ***int(20)***. Por lo tanto no entrara en la condición que dice porque la hora de inicio(`$hInicio`) es 15 y la hora de fin(`$hFin`) es 18, por lo tanto la condición queda de la siguiente forma:

```
Si ( 20>=15 y 20<=18 ) entonces redirecciona a bloqueo.html
```

No entrará en la condición porque 20>=15 si se cumple pero 20<=18 no porque 20 no es menor que 18.

Comment: sigue sin funcionar . @rene Limon.

Comment: Me ayudan a entenderlo ?  la cosa es que declaro 3 variables, le asigno un valor , a la última de las 3 le digo que va a ser entero la hora que me traiga el método date "G".  si la ultima es mayor o igual al inicio y menor o igual a fin me tendria que redirigir no?  que hora tengo que colocar para hacerlo ?

Comment: seria bueno que hicieras una prueba de escritorio. Pon en tu código **var_dump((int)date("G"));** y dime lo que te muestra

Comment: me aparece int(20) @Rene Limon

Comment: edité mi pregunta

Comment: Gracias por la explicación @Rene Limon. ¿Sabrás cómo hacer este ejemplo , no con números enteros sino con la hora con minutos? como tendria que hacer?

Comment: si miras este [manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) verás que a la función **date** le puedes pasar diferentes parámetros para que te devuelva los valores que deseas. Para  obtener los minutos debes utilizar la letra **i**. La función sería **date("i")** y te dará los minutos actuales. Esto lo puedes agregar a tu código para que definas variables de minutos y los compares tambien en un *if*

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que puedo ver el header que estas enviando esta mal escrito, cuando cambias un header como regla general se debe de escribir la variable con la primer letra de cada palabra con mayúscula, si hay más palabras en la variable se separa con "-" y para separar la variable del valor se usa un signo de ":" seguido de un espacio. Al tratar de cambiar la variable Location se debe de poner la variable con toda la URL incluido el protocolo, de la siguiente forma:

```
header("Location: http://localhost/bloqueo.php");
```

Puedes ver la documentación del header en http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php

Como tip adicional para sacar el nombre del servidor que estas usando puedes obtenerlo con $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Comment: Gracias @Tabitha , lo que sucede es que configure mi htaccess para que cuando no existiera la pagina ingresada me redirija a un archivo .php que contiene un efecto algo asi como "pagina no encontrada sera reedirigido en breve " , al hacer la confirmacion de este if , me redirige a un archivo que no existe en mi servidor lo que ejecuta todo lo demas . Voy a leer el manual con gusto. Mi problema estaba principalmente en el if , saludos.

Comment: Tus condiciones del if se ven bien, no se si las hayas editado y antes si estaban mal, ¿trataste de depurar el código imprimiendo lo que te regresan tus variables? También sería muy importante que revises en tu php.ini el valor de tu variable "date.timezone" luego PHP como no sabe el uso horario de tu sistema operativo uso otro

Comment: uso el default , alli me mostraba (20) al imprimir el resultado, pero cuando le agregue el set default time me regreso 14 alli fue cuando entendi lo de la hora (cosa que no sabía hasta hace media hora) y lo de la comparacion, 2 comparaciones en una que no volvian true porque una de las 2 no lo era usando el &&. Ya revise el php.ini del servidor. esta trayendome la misma hora . La cosa es que el valor de las horas esta no en hora, sino en numeros, pero por ahora funciona, ya veré como hacerlo con los minutos y segundos , ya hasta aquí para mi es un progreso (Y)

Comment: Que bueno, para sacarlo con horas, minutos y segundos te recomiendo usar las funciones time(), date('U',mktime(HH,MM,SS)) siento que sería mas fácil, de hecho para tu código no tendrías que agregarle ninguna linea adicional sólo cambiar unas asignaciones.